Help with xskak
I have some issues on xskak that I can't solve. I want to get 3 things.

Remove numbers and letters in rows and columns (their labels).
Highlight all the squares covered by the queen, I can do it just one by one.
The size of the board 10 by 10.
This is my attempt.

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\centering
  \chessboard[smallboard, showmover=false, setfen=8/8/8/8/2q,
     color=blue!25, colorbackfield=c1, pgfstyle=color, opacity=0.5,]
\end{document}


Everyone comes here for help, so a title like "Help with xskak" is a bit too general. Can you provide a more specific title that identifies the problem you're experiencing?

EDIT: The xskak documentation doesn't contain the instructions for creating chessboards. That's done by the chessboard package. The creator, Ulrike Fischer commented below that xskak will load chessboard. Therefore, following the documentation of chessboard you can try something like:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\centering
  \chessboard[smallboard, maxfield=j10,labelleft=false, labelbottom=false,showmover=false, setfen=1q//////K, color=blue!25, pgfstyle=color, opacity=0.5, markareas={b1-b9,c10-j10,a9-a10}, markfields={c9,d8,e7,f6,g5,h4,i3,j2}]
\end{document}

The screenshot below is the result. Note that I didn't include the square that the queen was on. Of course you can easily modify the code to get that if you want.


Good answer (+1). I did notice however that in most of your answers you provide a screenshot including the code in the editor. Maybe you want to show that the code really produces the result or something? However, it makes the actual result much smaller and the details are difficult to see - you could consider providing screenshots of the result only and not including the rest of the editor interface in your answers.

@Marijn Yes, as you said, it shows the code runs so if a person can't recreate it there isn't an extended back and forth conversation as to why the code doesn't work for them--they can see it should work. Therefore the problem is something else (e.g. which version of LaTeX is running). Also, clicking on the image makes it bigger (click again, bigger still)  so the details are easier to see. But sure, I will try to make screenshots bigger in the future.

the xskak package loads the chessboard package, so \usepackage{xskak} will work fine with your example too.

@UlrikeFischer Thanks. Have updated my answer to include your comment and enlarge the diagram for Marijn.
